# Fredholm operator and automorphism of unit disk

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Recently, I came across the following question while studying Fredholm operator. Recall an operator $S$ on a Hilbert space  $\mathcal H$ is said to be Fredholm if $Range(S)$ is closed along with both $ker S$ and $ker(S^*)$ is finite dimensional. My question is as follows:

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on separable complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ such that it's spectrum $\sigma(T) \subseteq \overline{\mathbb D}.$ Assume $(T-wI)$ is fredholm operator for every $w\in \mathbb D.$  Does it imply $\varphi(T)-w$ is also fredholm for every $w\in \mathbb D$ and for every automorphism  $\varphi$  of the unit disc $\mathbb D?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by automorphism of the disk you mean a biholomorphic map, yes.
Then $\varphi$ is of the form
$$
\varphi(z)=\frac{z-a}{\overline az-1}
$$
for some $a\in\mathbb D$.
A computation shows, that then
$$
\varphi(T)-w=\left( T-\frac{w-a}{1-w\overline a}\right)(1-w\overline a)(\overline aT-1)^{-1}
$$
is a product of a Fredholm times a scalar $\ne 0$ times an invertible operator, hence Fredholm.